# unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am new in here and want to ask something about removing duplicate data enter, right now I'm still doing my project about face recognition and stuck in remove duplicate data enter that I send to google sheets, this is the code that I use:

```
if(confidence <100):
    id = names[id]
    confidence = "{0}%".format (round(100-confidence))
    row = (id,datetime.datetime,now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
    index = 2
    sheet.insert_row (row,index)
    data = sheet.get_all_records()
    result = list(set(data))
    print (result)
```

The message error "unhashable type: 'dict"
I want to post the result in google sheet only once enter

Comment: You can not add a dictionary to a set.

Answer (score 2):

You can't add dictionaries to sets.

What you *can* do is add the dictionary items to the set. You can cast this to a list of tuples like so:

```
s = set(tuple(data.items()))
```

If you need to convert this back to a dictionary after, you can do:

```
for t in s:
    new_dict = dict(t)
```

Comment: i use the command "s = set(tuple(data.items()))" there is a new error.
the message " attributerror: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Comment: is `data` a list or a dictionary?

Comment: data is a list, and i want to remove the duplicate data enter in variable data,

Comment: If `data` is a list, then you shouldn't be getting an error saying *"unhashable type: 'dict"*. You can construct a set from a list directly: `s = set(data)`. Is there a part of your code that you didn't include?

Comment: if the data = dictionary why i get the error "objec has no attribute items"?. i have done to add the tuple

Comment: If `data` is a list, you shouldn't be getting the error *unhashable type: 'dict"*, meaning you should be able to convert it to a set simply by calling `set(data)`. If you are getting the error *unhashable type: 'dict"*, then you are trying to hash a dictionary somewhere. Please clarify the error you're getting when you try `set(data)`.

Comment: when i use the command set(data), message error will be "unhashable type: 'dict"

Comment: Then `data` is a dictionary, not a list.

Comment: so i must to convert data to dictionary first and then use set?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation of `gspread` `get_all_records()` returns **list** of **dicts** where dict has head row as key and value as cell value. So, you need to iterate through this list compare your `id`s to find and remove repeating items. Sample code:

```
visited = []
filtered = []
for row in data:
    if row['id'] not in visited:
        visited.append(row['id'])
    else:
        filtered.append(row)
```

Now, filtered should contain unique items. But instead of `id` you should put the name of the column which contains repeating value.

Comment: so i need to save the data that will be send to google sheets to empy variable first?

Comment: @RoyNvn What do you mean? In code which I attached iterates through list and add only unique items to it